# Only one resolution available 640 x 480 ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display, display-resolution

I am completely new to Ubuntu and I want to change my resolution as everything is so big that even navigating this site is a pain. I am running a GTX 1080 and when I check display options there is only one drop down option and that is 640 x 480. Is this a driver issue? Because this is what Windows did before I installed the driver. As I said I am completely new to Ubuntu and have just reformatted everything. The only thing I installed was my Linksys wusb6300 driver. I looked around but I can't quite find what I need. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Comment: Install `nvidia-367` driver.

Comment: Can you show me to a good tutorial I just tried to follow one I found on google and now when I boot up ubuntu I just a get a bluescreen. I am going to wipe ubuntu and reinstall it.

Comment: What is weird that if I go to advanced options and boot in recovery mode I have a more suitable resolution but now my wifi dongle driver does not work anymore. Does this mean i have to boot through recovery mode everytime or use my motherboards graphics processor? What the hell is going on?